# Http Listener not running in oracle forms 11g

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle11g

I am using oracle forms 11g with oracle database 10g. While running forms it's been showing an error that http listener is not running on port 7001. How can I resolve this? Error no is FRM-10142

Answer (score 0):

Run the Start Weblogic Admin Server from the start menu of your Oracle forms classic instance home menu, then you could be able to run your form.

Comment: I was able to resolve the above error by starting the server but now when the browser gets opened on running the form, it shows ora 12560-tns protocol adapter error. Reports are working fine in browser but i am not able to run the form. How can i resolve this??

Comment: If reports are running then forms should run also, you can try to restart the  tns listener from services in control panel.

Comment: I have tried this also but still forms are not running. I am not understanding why only forms are showing tns error while reports are working fine.

Comment: Are you able to connect in form builder (design time) ? if yes then it should connect at run time also, or it is something configuration related issue.

Comment: Yes, it gets connected at design time but still doesn't run.